# Number of way of choosing set of 5 books from 15

Tags: combinatorics

Consider a bookshelf with $15$ books placed in sequential manner.

In how many ways one can choose a set of $5$ books from this shelf so that no $2$ books in this set should be adjacently positioned at the time of picking ?

I tried this problem but was not able to find any way of interpreting it with combination and used brute force which in result gave wrong number.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: @ José Carlos Santos Thank you ! will keep in mind while posting subsequent doubts !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be found is the number of sums: $$a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5+a_6=10$$ where $a_1$ and $a_6$ are nonnegative integers and $a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5$ are positive integers.

Here $a_1$ stands for the number of books utmost right of the selected books, $a_6$ for the number of books utmost right of the selected books, and the other $a_i$ correspond with the number of books that divide two selected books (hence prevent them to be adjacent).

Setting $b_1=a_1$, $b_6=a_6$ and $b_i=a_i-1$ for $i=2,3,4,5$ that comes to the same as finding the number of sums: $$b_1+b_2+b_3+b_4+b_5+b_6=6$$ where $b_i$ is a nonnegative integer for $i=1,2,3,4,5,6$.

This can be solved with [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Give it a try yourself now, and eventually come back if you get stuck.

Comment: Your equation $b_1 + b_2 + b_3 + b_4 + b_5 + b_6 = 11$ is incorrect.  Replacing $a_i$ by $b_i + 1$ for $i = 2, 3, 4, 5$ with $a_1 = b_1$ and $a_6 = b_6$ gives $b_1 + b_2  + b_3 + b_4 + b_5 + b_6 + 4 = 10$, so the RHS should equal $6$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thank you! (Abusively of $15$ I subtracted $4$). I will repair.

Comment: @drhab Thank you for the explanation! Could you please tell me more of this equation the first one.what i understood from the question itself is that 
 choosing corner books would decrease both our selection "r" and "n" by 1.But choosing any middle one would decrease "n" by 2 and "r" by one because from middle we can`t choose both its neighbor.But i didn`t get this equation formation and here i am struggling to put up this in equation like this . So if you can explain a bit. Thank you!

Comment: Every correct selection will correspond with a tuple $\langle a_1,\dots,a_6\rangle$. If e.g. the selection looks like this: NSNNSNNNSNSNNNS then the tuple is $\langle1,2,3,1,3,0\rangle=\langle a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,a_6\rangle$. The first and last (corner) are nonnegative, the others positive. The job is to find out how many such tuples exist. Do you understand that?

Comment: @ drhab  Thanks i got it ! solved the problem.

Comment: That is nice to hear. You are very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The answer will be the same as # of ways of *inserting* each of the $5$ chosen books in gaps between the $10$ books left.

Don't forget the ends !